# img crawler AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'img' python 3.7.6 beautifulsoup4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.122 Safari/537.36"
}

def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        for item in range(1, 3):
            print(f"Extracting Page# {item}")
            r = req.get(url.format(item), headers=headers)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser', from_encoding='utf-8')

            if 'http' in item.img['src']:
                target = [[item.img['alt'], f'{item.img["src"]}']
                      for item in soup.select("dt.image")]

            else:
                target = [[item.img['alt'], f'https:{item.img["src"]}']
                      for item in soup.select("dt.image")]

            for el in target:
                print(f"{el[0]}.jpg")
                r = req.get(el[1])
                with open(f"{el[0]}.jpg", 'wb') as f:
                    f.write(r.content)


main("https://www.coupang.com/np/categories/311357?page={}")
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please have a look at this and edit your question afterwards: [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Change  from  `if 'http' in item.img['src']:`  to `if 'http' in soup.img['src']:`

Answer (score 0):

you are storing `item` as a int in for loop: `for item in range(1, 3)`. Then you're trying to apply a `.img` function on that. What you actually want to apply that to is your beautifulsoup object `soup`

you also need to clean up your list comprehension too. In one of them, you correctly concatenate `'https:`, and the other one, you don't.

Take a look here and see the modifications I made to your code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.122 Safari/537.36"
}

def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        for item in range(1, 3):
            print(f"Extracting Page# %s" %item)
            r = req.get(url.format(item), headers=headers)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser', from_encoding='utf-8')

            if 'http' in soup.img['src']:
                target = [[each.img['alt'], 'https:' + each.img["src"]]
                      for each in soup.select("dt.image")]

            else:
                target = [[each.img['alt'], 'https:' + each.img["src"]]
                      for each in soup.select("dt.image")]

            for el in target:
                print('%s.jpg' %el[0])
                r = req.get(el[1])
                with open('%s.jpg' %el[0], 'wb') as f:
                    f.write(r.content)


main("https://www.coupang.com/np/categories/311357?page={}")
```